# Prove the convergence in distribution of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a discrete valued random variable and $Z \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be continuous random variable. Both $U$ and $Z$ have finite mean and variance and are independent. I want to prove the following statements as $\varepsilon \to 0$:

\begin{align}
(a)\ \  &U+ \varepsilon Z  \xrightarrow{\mathcal{d}} U \\
(b) \ \ & (U,U+\varepsilon Z) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{d}} (U,U) 
\end{align}
where $X_n \xrightarrow{d} Y$ means $X_n$ converges in law to $Y$.

Can anyone guide me in this?

My attempt: Let $\Phi$ denote the characteristic function. So $\Phi_{U+\varepsilon Z}(t)=\Phi_U(t) \Phi_{\varepsilon Z}(t)=\Phi_U(t) \Phi_Z(t\varepsilon)=\Phi_U(t) \mathbb{E}[e^{i t \varepsilon Z}]$. Since $|e^{i t \varepsilon Z}|=1$ and $e^{i t \varepsilon Z} \to 1$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, is it justified to say that $\mathbb{E}[e^{i t \varepsilon Z}] \to 1$ and thus $ U+ \varepsilon Z  \xrightarrow{\mathcal{d}} U $?

I think the same reasoning should also hold for $(b)$.

Comment: The characteristic function is continuous. So then its limit at any point is ...?

Comment: @Calculon: The function evaluated at the limit.

Comment: and what is the characteristic function evaluated at zero?

Comment: @Calculon: Yeah,  it's 1. So the justification is valid.

Comment: Or: *pointwise (almost sure)  convergence implies convergence in probability, which in turn implies convergence in distribution*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest a proof that does not use the characteristic function.

We say that $X_n \xrightarrow[]{d} X$ when (See the [Portemanteau Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures))
  $$ \text{For every open set } A: \liminf_n\Bbb{P}(X_n \in A)\geq \Bbb{P}(X \in A)$$
or equivalently
  $$\text{For every closed set } F:\limsup_n\Bbb{P}(X_n \in F)\leq \Bbb{P}(X \in F)$$

In the case a), define $F^\delta = \{x \mid d(x,F)<\delta\}$

$$\Bbb{P}(U + \epsilon Z \in F )  \leq \Bbb{P} (U \in F^\delta) + \Bbb{P} (|\epsilon Z| \geq \delta) $$
Therefore for every $\delta >0$
 $$\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0}\Bbb{P}(U + \epsilon Z \in F )  \leq \Bbb{P} (U \in F^\delta) $$

This implies that
 $$\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0}\Bbb{P}(U + \epsilon Z \in F )  \leq \Bbb{P} (U \in F) $$

so $U + \epsilon Z\xrightarrow[\epsilon \to 0]{d} U $

For the case b)

consider the closed set $F$
 $$\Bbb{P}( (U,U + \epsilon Z) \in F )  \leq \Bbb{P} ((U,U) \in F^\delta) + \Bbb{P} (|\epsilon Z| \geq \delta) $$
Therefore for every $\delta >0$
 $$\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0}\Bbb{P}( (U,U + \epsilon Z) \in F)  \leq \Bbb{P} ((U,U) \in F^\delta) $$

This implies that
 $$\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0}\Bbb{P}( (U,U + \epsilon Z) \in F)  \leq \Bbb{P} ((U,U) \in F) $$

so $(U,U + \epsilon Z)\xrightarrow[\epsilon \to 0]{d} (U,U) $